# WPF DataGrid HeaderStyle

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid where I'd like to style column headers differently. The styles are stored in a resource dictionary that gets loaded and merged into the window. If I have a header defined like the following:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Uid="columnPartNumber" x:Name="columnPartNumber" Header="Part #"                                             
                         HeaderStyle="{DynamicResource PartsPartNumberHeader}">
```

The header style is not applied.

If I instead have a style on the entire datagrid

```
 <DataGrid  CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      SelectionMode="Single"                      
                      Style="{DynamicResource PartsPartListDataGrid}">
```

And in my style I am setting the ColumnHeaderStyle property, that style will get applied to all of my columns. Is HeaderStyle not the correct property to use to style individual column headers? Can that not be set using a DynamicResource?

Styles in the same resource dictionary file:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="BasePartListColumnHeader" >
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    </Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="PartsPartListPartNumberHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource BasePartListColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    </Style>

 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="PartsPartListDataGrid">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="../resources/Futura Font Family/#Futura Std Book" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,10,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="white"/>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="Horizontal" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource PartsPartListRowStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{DynamicResource PartsPartListCellStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource BasePartListColumnHeader}" />
        <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
    </Style>
```

*edit
Well, it's not the prettiest, but if I apply the style in the Loaded event of my control in the code then it works.

```
 object headerStyle = this.TryFindResource("PartsPartListPartNumberHeader");
            if (headerStyle != null)
            {
                columnPartNumber.HeaderStyle = (Style)headerStyle;
            }
```

Comment: Are `PartsPartListDataGrid` and `PartsPartNumberHeader` defined in the same resource dictionary? What's the `TargetType` of `PartsPartNumberHeader`? I did a quick test with the style defined in the same XAML file as the DataGrid, and `HeaderStyle` worked fine, as I'd expect.

Comment: Updated question with styles

Comment: Whoops, I was wrong: My style works in the XAML designer, not at runtime. Yours doesn't work at runtime either for me.

Comment: `HeaderStyle="{StaticResource PartsPartListPartNumberHeader}"` works for me at runtime.

Comment: I can't use a StaticResource because my ResourceDictionary is loaded from a separate file, not defined in the windows resources.

Comment: What do you mean, "loaded from a separate file"; loaded at runtime using `XamlReader.Parse()` or some equivalent?

Comment: Yes loaded at runtime